# How does dividing remove repetitions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I've been trying to visually wrap my head around how in problems involving combinations and permutations, dividing removes repetitions?

Like for example a simple question like: In how many ways can you re-arrange the letters in the word "SEE". It would be **3!/2!**

But I can't **visually** understand how dividing by 2! works? How does it eliminate the identical possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's distinguish the two $E$s, lets say as $E_1$ and $E_2$. Then we take all possible permutations of the 3 (now distinct letters). If we consider any such permutation, say $E_1 \ S \ E_2$, then there is always another **distinct** permutation obtained by exchanging the positions of the indexed $E's$ that will give me the same word if I ignore the subscripts $1$ and $2$. So counting every permutation of the three letters has counted every word twice, and so we have to divide by two to get the right answer.

**EDIT** (in response to the comment):
Suppose you have $10$ numbers as follows: $1,1,3,3,6,6,9,9,15,15$ (think of every number as an arrangement without subscripts).
Now you decide to remove the repetition corresponding to $1,3,6,9,15$. So, as you mention, we resort to subtraction. So out of the 2 copies of every number, we remove one and **keep the other**. That is the frequency of every number is halved. And so the overall division by $2$.

Have a look at the following for better intuition of why division works: [Division using repeated subtraction](http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/factsheet/ma12pape-l1-f-division-using-repeated-subtraction)

Comment: But how does the dividing operation actually remove the over-count? What I mean is why dividing works instead of subtraction?

Comment: Because for **every** single arrangement, there is another arrangement which is similar after removing the subscripts. So, you need to **subtract repeatedly** for **every** double-counted arrangement. And may I ask you, what is repeated subtraction? - Division